# Protected и производный класс

Tags: классы, c++

Доброго времени суток

Есть такой пример

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class CL
{
protected:
    int a;
public:
    CL():a(6)
    {}
};

class DCL:public CL
{
public:
    DCL():CL()
    {}
    void fnc_dcl(const DCL& rhs)
    {
        cout<<rhs.a;
    }
    void fnc_cl(const CL& rhs)
    {
        cout<<rhs.a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CL cl;
    DCL dcl1,dcl2;
    dcl1.fnc_dcl(dcl2);
    dcl1.fnc_cl(cl);
    return 0;
}
```

Возник такой вопрос: почему в функции fnc_cl не видно protected-элемента "a" базового класса CL? protected он ведь на то и protected, что должен быть виден производным классам, а DCL производный от CL. Понятно, что rhs - это другой объект, поэтому, может быть, и не видно в нем, но fnc_dcl, в свою очередь, работает нормально (кстати, конструкторы копирования, определенные пользователем, тоже нормально копируют закрытые данные). Здесь же fnc_dcl работает нормально, а в fnc_cl появляется ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ответ на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270941/cannot-access-protected-member-of-base-class-in-derived-class).